# Android: socket.io io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: XHR poll error

Tags: android, socket.io

Sometimes I get this error:

> io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: xhr poll error

My code for connecting to the socket:

```
try {
    HostnameVerifier myHostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            return true;
        }
    };
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts= new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }

        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return new X509Certificate[0];
        }
    }};

    SSLContext mySSLContext = null;
    try {
        mySSLContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        try {
            mySSLContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, null);
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().hostnameVerifier(myHostnameVerifier).sslSocketFactory(mySSLContext.getSocketFactory()).build();


    IO.setDefaultOkHttpWebSocketFactory(okHttpClient);
    IO.setDefaultOkHttpCallFactory(okHttpClient);

    IO.Options opts = new IO.Options();
    opts.callFactory = okHttpClient;
    opts.webSocketFactory = okHttpClient;

    G.socket = IO.socket(G.SOCKET_ADDRESS, opts);
    G.socket.connect();
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    Log.i("errorCheck", "E: "+e);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But sometimes it works fine. At other times, it doesn't.
I use `HTTPS`, but it doesn't work on the 443 port.
I get all permissions from the user and sometimes `socket.io` works fine.

How I can fix it to make it work all the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I changed transport from `polling` to `websocket` and my problem fixed ( client and server side )

Android :

```
IO.Options opts = new IO.Options();
opts.transports = new String[] { WebSocket.NAME };

socket = IO.socket(SOCKET_ADDRESS, opts);
socket.connect();
```

Server :

```
io.set('transports', ['websocket']);
```

Comment: I get an ```io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: websocket error``` after adding the transport

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem so I just changed the Socket.IO Java client version from 1 to 2

```
Compatibility
Client version  Socket.IO server
0.9.x            1.x
1.x 2.x          (or 3.1.x / 4.x with allowEIO3: true)
2.x              3.x / 4.x
```

Gradle
Add it as a gradle dependency for Android Studio, in build.gradle:

```
implementation ('io.socket:socket.io-client:2.1.0') {
  // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
  exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
}
```