# Socket io is not connect nodejs with android (Client) in HTTPS

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io

Simply passing text form NodeJS Socket io to android client using Self signed certificate (HTTPS) added with NodeJS, I got error

Added: android:usesCleartextTraffic="true", Internet Permission

Error:  I/IO connect_error: com.github.nkzawa.engineio.client.EngineIOException: xhr poll error

I tried [Android: socket.io io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: XHR poll error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57637856/android-socket-io-io-socket-engineio-client-engineioexception-xhr-poll-error)

In that answer io.set('transports', ['websocket']); want to added in nodejs server but, I added in my server I got error

```
Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'transports' of undefined
```

Help me to solve this problem

App.js

```
const express = require('express')
const https = require('https')
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const app = express()
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var io = require('socket.io')(https);

io.on('connection',function(socket){
    
    console.log('one user connected '+socket.id);
    socket.emit('CHAT',{"message":"hy"});
    socket.on('disconnect',function(){
        console.log('one user disconnected '+socket.id);
    });

})

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log('You are now connected with mysql database...')
  });

app.use('/',(req,res,next) => {
    res.send('Hello from SSL server!!!')
})

const sslServer = https.createServer(
    {
        key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'cert','key.pem')),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'cert','cert.pem')),
    },
    app
)
sslServer.listen(3000, () => console.log("Secure Server on port 3000"))
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Button button1;
    public TextView text1,text2,text3,text4;
    public EditText edit1;
    public String message;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        button1 =  findViewById(R.id.button);
        text1 =   findViewById(R.id.textview);
        edit1 =   findViewById(R.id.edit);
//        mSocket.connect();
        text1.setText("");

        final String uri = "https://192.168.43.182:3000";
        try {
            // Load CAs from an InputStream.
            CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            Certificate certificate = certificateFactory.generateCertificate(
                    getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.cert)); // from file server.crt
            // Create a KeyStore containing the trusted CAs.
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            keyStore.load(null, null);
            keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", certificate);
            // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in KeyStore.
            TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(
                    TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);
            // Create an SSLContext that uses the TrustManager.
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);
            Log.i("uri", "sslContext created");

            IO.setDefaultSSLContext(sslContext);
            IO.Options options = new IO.Options();
            options.secure = true;
            options.path = "/web-live";
            options.reconnection = true;
            options.upgrade = true;
            options.sslContext = sslContext;
            URL url = new URL(uri);
            final HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpsURLConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
            httpsURLConnection.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    Log.i("HostnameVerifier", "Approving certificate for " + hostname);
                    return true; // Do nothing.
                }
            });
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                httpsURLConnection.getInputStream()));
                        Log.i("httpsURLConnection", "url connected");
                        String line; //FIXME: readLine kicks in socket.io at least on gingerbread!?
                        while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                            Log.i("httpsURLConnection", line);
                        }

                        in.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    }
                }
            }).start();
            Socket socket = IO.socket(uri, options);
            socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    for(Object o : args) {
                        Log.i("IO " + Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, o.toString());
                    }
                }
            }).on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    Log.i("IO", Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT);
                }
            }).on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    Log.i("IO", Socket.EVENT_CONNECT);
                }
            }).on("secure_data", new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    Log.i("IO secure_data", args[0].toString());
                }
            });
            socket.connect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Keys are generated by the openssl its works fine when using RestApi. I got only connection problem  help me to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the following may be between client and server

- check the version socket.io you using in client side is supporting the version using on Server(Nodejs) side
- some time the multiple request or multiple instance generated from client side before connecting or sending request successfully as
  pending so try to disconnect proper before create new instance.
- try to update the transport from polling to websocket

Please check the below line of code may help you

```
public void initSocket() {
        try {
            SSLContext mySSLContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            mySSLContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());

            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .hostnameVerifier(myHostnameVerifier)
                    .sslSocketFactory(mySSLContext.getSocketFactory(), (X509TrustManager) trustAllCerts[0])
                    .build();

            IO.setDefaultOkHttpWebSocketFactory(okHttpClient);
            IO.setDefaultOkHttpCallFactory(okHttpClient);

            IO.Options opts = new IO.Options();
            opts.callFactory = okHttpClient;
            opts.webSocketFactory = okHttpClient;
            opts.timeout = 60 * 1000;
            opts.forceNew = false;
            opts.secure = true;
            opts.reconnection = true;

            mSocket = IO.socket(socketUrl, opts);
            mSocket.connect();

            mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"socket connected");
                }
            }).on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"socket disconnected");
                }
            }).on(Socket.EVENT_ERROR, new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"socket error");
                }

            }).on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"socket connection timeout");
                }
            });

        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


   TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
        }

        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                       String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                       String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }
    }};

    HostnameVerifier myHostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            return true;
        }
    };
```

Comment: My nodejs version "socket.io": "^2.3.0" and android -  "io.socket:socket.io-client:2.0.0"

Comment: Please read the detail https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java to check version mismatch in client server, also please first disconnect when initialize socket object and connect in your flow and then check isConnected or not if connected then request or process with server otherwise you will get error